# Upgrade package requires Ubuntu Pro with esm-apps

Tags: apt, upgrade

i have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which is not EOL yet.
If i do apt upgrade it shows this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  python3-rsa
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Why? Does it mean there is upgrade of python3-rsa but i will not get it because i have no Ubuntu Pro enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `python3-rsa` package is in Ubuntu's `universe` repository (not `main`).

Canonical engineers have always provided security updates for packages in main. The Ubuntu community has always been responsible for universe (so it often didn't get done).

Ubuntu Pro is a subscription service with several features. The relevant feature here is that Canonical engineers will also do those universe patches. That's all. You are seeing an advertisement for that subscription service.

In other words, you were never getting security patches for your universe packages, and were blind to that. Now you still aren't getting those patches, but are no longer blind.

Your apt output will change again when your release reaches EOL.

Answer (score 0):

This message doesn't require anything. It tells that you can get "more security updates" if you subscribe to "Ubuntu Pro"

The message is not related to any specific package.